# Why are the english letters of wav2vec2 tokenizer aren't order as abc characters order?

Tags: huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

I looked on the Tokenizer of `facebook/wav2vec2-base-960h`

from:
https://huggingface.co/facebook/wav2vec2-base-960h/blob/main/vocab.json

and I see that the letters are not order by the `abc` order, for example:

```
"E": 5, 
"T": 6,
"A": 7,
"O": 8,
```

Why they didn't order it as:

```
"A": 5, 
"B": 6,
"C": 7,
"D": 8, 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is based on the frequency of occurrence of the letters in the training data used to train the model